# Rename database file in ExternalFilesDir in Android

Tags: android, file-rename, android-external-storage

I am copying my pre-populated database from Assets to app's external files directory. My code is -

```
private boolean copyDatabaseFromAssets(Context context, String databaseName , boolean overwrite)  {

    String outputFile_path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + databaseName;
    File outputFile = new File(outputFile_path);

    if (outputFile.exists() && !overwrite) {
        return true;
    }

    outputFile_path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + databaseName + ".temp";
    outputFile = new File(outputFile_path);
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Initial File Path : " + outputFile_path);
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "Initial File : " + outputFile);
    outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(databaseName);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        outputFile_path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + databaseName;
        outputFile = new File(outputFile_path);
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Final File Path : " + outputFile_path);
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Final File : " + outputFile);

        if(outputFile.renameTo(outputFile)){
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Rename was successful!");
        } else {
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Rename was NOT successful!");
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.delete();
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Yes, the mentioned code does copy the database from assets folder to app's external directory. But, the problem I am facing is - **database does Not get renamed back to it's original name.** My relevant logcat is -

```
11-25 21:07:01.487 24573-24573/? D/MainActivity: Initial File Path : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/in.atultiwari.testapp/files/mydb.db.temp
11-25 21:07:01.487 24573-24573/? D/MainActivity: Initial File : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/in.atultiwari.testapp/files/mydb.db.temp
11-25 21:07:01.509 24573-24573/? D/MainActivity: Final File Path : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/in.atultiwari.testapp/files/mydb.db
11-25 21:07:01.509 24573-24573/? D/MainActivity: Final File : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/in.atultiwari.testapp/files/mydb.db
11-25 21:07:01.510 24573-24573/? D/MainActivity: Rename was NOT successful!
```

I am also using following permissions in manifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

It's been hours I am unable to figure out, where am I making mistake?

Comment: Both `Final File` and `Final File Path ` name is same so probably occurring issue  try it after changing `databaseName ` to some other name

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK sorry I didn't get you properly. `Final file` is type file (`outputFile`) which contains `final file name` as string (`outputFile_path`). So their Logcat would be same but they are both of different types. Or if you are pointing towards initial and final names then the string for final file path must is updated. So, initial and final paths / strings are different (as also seen in logcat)

Comment: I mean you have `databaseName="mydb.db";` right? try by changing it to `databaseName="mydb_new.db";`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Ok. I will try and get back. Thanks.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thank you Sir. I read and re-read this code a hundred times in last few hours and everytime I missed the fact that, at the time of renaming database back to original name I am unwittingly messing up with `temporary database name`, And all this is because I thought, I could make this code work with having single variable having different values at different occasions. You have a sharp mind and eyes to catch that. :)